# Core Text returns absurd font bounding boxes for certain system fonts?

Tags: core-text

I am playing around with CoreText and note the function `CTFontGetBoundingBox` returns abnormally large height for certain fonts. Here is a snippet for Swift Playground that I retrieve these data:

```
import CoreText

extension CGFloat {
    var string: String {
        return String(format: "%.2f", self)
    }
}

func getFontMetrics(fontName: String) -> (String, String, String, String) {
    let font = CTFontCreateWithName(fontName as CFString, 50.0, nil)
    return (CTFontGetDescent(font).string, CTFontGetAscent(font).string, CTFontGetLeading(font).string, CTFontGetBoundingBox(font).height.string)
}

getFontMetrics(fontName: "Times-Roman")
getFontMetrics(fontName: "TimesNewRomanPSMT")
getFontMetrics(fontName: "Zapfino")
getFontMetrics(fontName: "Helvetica")
getFontMetrics(fontName: "HelveticaNeue")
getFontMetrics(fontName: "PingFangSC-Regular")
```

Most data look fine, but the results for `Times-Roman` and `Zapfino` are way off the normal range, which are

```
(.0 "12.50", .1 "37.50", .2 "0.00", .3 "84.99")
(.0 "75.13", .1 "93.75", .2 "0.00", .3 "294.75")
```

(`Times-Roman` on top and `Zapfino` on bottom; from left to right: descent, ascent, leading / line gap, bounding box’s height)

As a comparison with normal data, here is what for `TimesNewRomanPSMT`:

```
(.0 "10.82", .1 "44.56", .2 "2.12", .3 "65.67")
```

I dumped some data from Zapfino, and it seems that the bounding box is close to `usWinDescent` plus `usWinAscent`:

```
<sTypoAscender value="677"/>
<sTypoDescender value="-514"/>
<sTypoLineGap value="0"/>
<usWinAscent value="750"/>
<usWinDescent value="1264"/>
```

(750+1264)/677 = 2.97, whereas 294.75/93.75 = 3.144, but I am not sure what is going on here exactly.

My question is: why sometimes bounding boxes’ behavior are so strange? Where do these data come from? Under which circumstances should I use `CTFontGetBoundingBox`?

Answer (score 0):

There’s nothing abnormal with the results you get. That is exactly how font data works and Core Text returns all values as expected. The thing is that a font’s bounding box is intimately tied to its glyphs’ outlines, whereas the ascent, descent, and leading metrics define the font’s intended line spacing. These metrics are independent of the actual glyph outlines that may and often do exceed the line height in both directions. This can be seen in glyphs with more complex diacritical marks, for example. It’s also quite evident in the kind of non-utilitarian designs like Zapfino with its excessive calligraphic swashes. In such cases, the bounding box can differ from the line metrics considerably.